# MS Access Navigation control

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I am having an issue with VBA on the Navigation control tool in Access.
[Picture here](http://postimg.org/image/oyblm16e3/)
So if I want to change the value of the ID textbox above, I try these commands, none of them working:

```
Text_ID.Value = 1  
Form.Text_ID.Value = 1  
Me.Text_ID.Value = 1
```

Same thing if I want to change the Record Source:

```
Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID = " & Form.Text_ID.Value & ";"
```

Do you know what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is the object's correct name?

Comment: The ID on your form is a comboBox -- not a textbox (unless you are faking it to look like one). How are you populating that control? Are you expecting the form to display a record if you change the value in 'Text_ID'? If so, you need an 'After_Update' event.